# Combining multiple columns in Excel while keeping a reference cell the same

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to convert data like this:

| Name | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Date 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | 10 Jan | 14 Mar | 19 Apr | 3 Dec |
| Name 2 | 14 Feb | 16 May | 2 Oct | 21 Nov |
| Name 3 | 19 Sep | 25 Dec | 5 Jun | 28 Aug |

Into this:

| Name | Dates |
| --- | --- |
| Name 1 | 10 Jan |
| Name 1 | 14 Mar |
| Name 1 | 19 April |
| Name 1 | 3 Dec |
| Name 2 | 14 Feb |
| Name 2 | 16 May |
| Name 2 | 2 Oct |
| Name 2 | 21 Nov |
| Name 3 | 19 Sep |
| etc |  |

The goal is to create a list so I can sort by date and create a calendar schedule.

I've tried pivot tables and can't seem to get it to work. I don't want to merge the name and date cells because then the sorting would mess up. I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing.

I could manually create the list by copy-pasting the columns next to each other but this data is going to be updated regularly so I'm looking for an automatic/formula type solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using a combination of `HSTACK()` & `TOCOL()`

[image]

---

```
=LET(α, B2:E4, HSTACK(TOCOL(IF(α<>"",A2:A4)),TOCOL(α)))
```

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Name", type text}, {"Value", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

One can modify the formula to make it bit more dynamic and reusable across the worksheets by defining it in the name manager as `UNPIVOT()` and refer the formula as

```
=LAMBDA(array,
         LET(
             _data, array,
             _name, TAKE(_data,,1),
             _date, DROP(_data,,1),
             HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(_date<>"",_name),3),TOCOL(_date,2))))
```

---

And then use in the worksheet as

```
=UNPIVOT(A2:E4)
```

---

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, I used the Power Query method and it worked perfectly.